# Error while trying to implement the reducer method transforming an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

hope you are doing good in this quarantine, I have like an hour and a half trying to look for my issue in this code, I desire you to help me in this exercise,
I have this array,

```
[
  {
    id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a126",
    creationDate: "2020-05-05",
    percentage: "3.62%",
    quantity: 21,
    requestType: "1-Cash Advance",
    timePercentage: "0:23:27",
    totalCalls: 580,
    totalTime: "8:21;00"
  },
  {
    id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a127",
    creationDate: "2020-05-05",
    percentage: "57.41%",
    quantity: 333,
    requestType: "2-Info Request",
    timePercentage: "0:47:18",
    totalCalls: 580,
    totalTime: "262:49;00"
  },
    {
    id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a126",
    creationDate: "2020-05-06",
    percentage: "3.62%",
    quantity: 21,
    requestType: "1-Cash Advance",
    timePercentage: "0:23:27",
    totalCalls: 580,
    totalTime: "8:21;00"
  },
  {
    id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a127",
    creationDate: "2020-05-06",
    percentage: "57.41%",
    quantity: 333,
    requestType: "2-Info Request",
    timePercentage: "0:47:18",
    totalCalls: 580,
    totalTime: "262:49;00"
  }
]
```

this is my reduce implementation,

result is the previous object array,

```
    result = Object.values(
        result.reduce((object, {creationDate,
            requestType, quantity,
            totalTime, timePercentage,
            percentage, totalCalls
        }) => {

            if(!object[requestType]) object[requestType] = {
                requestType, quantity, totalTime,
                timePercentage, percentage, totalCalls
            };

            if(object[requestType].requestType === requestType){
                object[requestType].quantity += quantity;
                if(object[requestType].creationDate !== creationDate) object[requestType].totalCalls += totalCalls;
            }
            return object;
        })
    )
```

what I was expecting is this

```
[
    {
        percentage: "3.62%",
        quantity: 42,
        requestType: "1-Cash Advance",
        timePercentage: "0:46:54",
        totalCalls: 1160,
        totalTime: "16:42;00"
    },
    {
        percentage: "57.41%",
        quantity: 666,
        requestType: "2-Info Request",
        timePercentage: "01:33:48",
        totalCalls: 1160,
        totalTime: "525:38:00"
    }
]
```

Pls do not care about the fancy part I just want like a general idea, I hope I can resolve this by my self but I do not like to get stuck so I will keep trying to look for a solution while waiting for someone to help my with my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the `result` object and real code not some screenshots. As far as i understand you want to merge those objects into one?

Comment: Yes I want to merge it

Comment: It would easier if you can share a demo array and an expected result array.

Comment: Alright, I made a modification in the question

Comment: Thanks but i think the expecting result has some issues, Would you please recheck? Also please share what you've tried?

Comment: Ready, the code in the question is what I have right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add initial value. 
check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> initialValue Optional
>
> A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the
>   callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the
>   array will be used as the initial accumulator value and skipped as
>   currentValue.

here is the working code

```
let result = [{
        id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a126",
        creationDate: "2020-05-05",
        percentage: "3.62%",
        quantity: 21,
        requestType: "1-Cash Advance",
        timePercentage: "0:23:27",
        totalCalls: 580,
        totalTime: "8:21;00"
    },
    {
        id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a127",
        creationDate: "2020-05-05",
        percentage: "57.41%",
        quantity: 333,
        requestType: "2-Info Request",
        timePercentage: "0:47:18",
        totalCalls: 580,
        totalTime: "262:49;00"
    },
    {
        id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a126",
        creationDate: "2020-05-06",
        percentage: "3.62%",
        quantity: 21,
        requestType: "1-Cash Advance",
        timePercentage: "0:23:27",
        totalCalls: 580,
        totalTime: "8:21;00"
    },
    {
        id: "5eb2d53443ba03249056a127",
        creationDate: "2020-05-06",
        percentage: "57.41%",
        quantity: 333,
        requestType: "2-Info Request",
        timePercentage: "0:47:18",
        totalCalls: 580,
        totalTime: "262:49;00"
    }
];

let aggregatedObject = [];

result = Object.values(result.reduce((aggregatedObject, {
    creationDate,
    requestType,
    quantity,
    totalTime,
    timePercentage,
    percentage,
    totalCalls
}) => {

    if (!aggregatedObject[requestType]) {
        aggregatedObject[requestType] = {
            requestType,
            quantity,
            totalTime,
            timePercentage,
            percentage,
            totalCalls
        };
    }

    if (aggregatedObject[requestType].requestType === requestType) {
        aggregatedObject[requestType].quantity += quantity;
        if (aggregatedObject[requestType].creationDate !== creationDate) {
            aggregatedObject[requestType].totalCalls += totalCalls;
        }
    }
    return aggregatedObject;
}, aggregatedObject));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your reply have helped me alot!